# Applying AM-GM inequality to terms

Tags: calculus

Very dumb question can anyone fill in the detail for me?
By AM-GM inequality we have $x^n(n-nx)\leq(\frac{n}{n+1})^{n+1}, x\in [0,1]$

Here is what I tried AM-GM inequality says $a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot\dots   a_n \leq \frac{\sqrt[n]{(\sum^n_1 a_i)}}{n}$. So if I do $a_n=x^n(n-nx))\implies x^2(-n)\cdot x^3(-2n)\dots x^{n+1}(-n)\leq \frac{\sqrt[n+1]{\sum^{n+1}_{i=1}x^i(n-ni)}}{n}$, I am having a hard time getting to the above inequality.

any help or hints is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. The AM-GM inequality says: $\sqrt[n+1]{x^n\cdot (n-nx)} = \sqrt[n+1]{x\cdot x\cdot x\cdots (n-nx)} \le \dfrac{x+x+x+\cdots + (n-nx)}{n+1} = \dfrac{n}{n+1}$. Raising both sides to the $(n+1)^{\text{th}}$ power to get the desire inequality. Note that in the above numerator there are a total of $n$ such $x$'s, hence the $nx$ get canceled and leaving only $n$ left.

Comment: ah thanks! Just to make sure I understood , you took $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_{n}=x$ and $a_{n+1}=(n-nx)$?

Comment: @Remu:  That is correct.